# Skip request filter for specific resource in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Iam working on a jersey project and Iam using token authentication and am using ContainerRequestFilter for filtering all the request and checking whether it has a token with it, but the requests includes Login and registration request, but we need to skip these request.. How i can skip the filtering for login and registration requests? Is there any mechanism in jersey for achieving this?

thank you

Comment: Assuming Jersey 2, see [Dynamic Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9955)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no facility fo such a behavior using a raw deployment descriptor (*web.xml*).

However, if that was a custom filter, you can get it skip the **excluded paths** using a simple check on request url in your `doFilter()` method. But since you are using a third party filter, that won't be the way to go with but still can have this functionality achieved:

1. Change your third party filter (`ContainerRequestFilter`) mapping to another path rather than a wildcard one:

   ```
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>containerRequestFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/tokenizedpaths/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. Declare a new filter (you will see in a moment what it looks like), that will be mapped to a wildcard path to filter all requests and be delegated to dispatch requests to your *containerRequestFilter* only if the request path does not match the excluded path(s) (I've choosen *register* as a sample):

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>filteringFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.sample.FilteringServletFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>excludedPaths</param-name>
       <param-value>/register</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>
   ```
3. The `FilteringServletFilter` will look like somthing like the following:

   ```
   public class FilteringServletFilter implements Filter {

     private List<String> excludedPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

     public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
       // You can declare a comma separated list to hold your excluded paths
       this.excludedPaths = Arrays.asList(config.getInitParameter("excludedPaths").split(","));
     }

     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
       // If the url is one of excluded paths, then just continue with next filter
       if (this.excludedPaths.contains(path)) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response); 
         return;
       }
       // Otherwilse, forward the request to the needed filter
       else {
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/tokenizedpaths" + path).forward(request, response);
       }
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: `ContainerRequestFilter ` isn't third party. It is a Jersey class, which has nothing to do with Servlet filters.